# React Node Download file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

**Node**:

```
try {
    const file = `Invoice#4585.pdf`;
    res.download(file);
    console.log('download completed');


} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

This is working in postman, issue while calling the api from react

**React**:

```
const response = yield call(fetch, "url", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
});
```

I am getting error on react side
SyntaxError: Unexpected token % in JSON at position 0

Answer (score 0):

The response schema probabbly isn't in **.json** i think.
It's can be **blob**

> A Blob object represents a file-like object of immutable, raw data;
>   they can be read as text or binary data

try this:

```
fetch(`http://localhost:4000/pdf`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
  }
})
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(response => {
    //Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
    console.log(response);
    const file = new Blob([response], {
      type: "application/pdf"
    });

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

---

You can also convert PDF -> JSON on backend side:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf2json

Comment: I tried this. I am still getting same error. The node respnse is something like this,
%PDF-1.3
%ÿÿÿÿ
9 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/ca 1
>>
and it continues further

Comment: I tried to hit the api with window.open( apicall ). Then I am able to download the file but I am not sure if this is a standard way to it. Can anybody please help me on this

Comment: You Can delete windowsOpen and add file to state

Comment: I tried with axios and it worked for me. Thanks for  the help.

Comment: Glad to hear - it was blob?

Comment: The only change I did was , I used axios and it worked.
Thanks for the help